# Why is didRangeBeaconsInRegion called two times in using altBeacon android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

before everything , I have read all discussion about didRangeBeaconsInRegion multiple times in GitHub and stack-overflow. I used **beaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers()** in my code, nothing changed.
I use altbeacon library for scanning UUIDs. at first I just used StartRanginginRegion and StopRanginginRegion when I wanted to stop scaning. it caused a problem. it seemed the UUIDs got cached for one time , when I disconnect my ibeacon power. still found. after that I used StartMonitorInRegion as well as StartRanginginRegion and never stopped MonitorInRegion. my App supposed to scan one time automatically and stop, then the user can start it manually by clicking button then again stop after foregroundScanPeriod time. in my final code new problem is appeared. didRangeBeaconsInRegion function called two times in each start/stop scan. When I run the fragment and start scanning is run. in each foregroundScanPeriod for example I get beacon.size>0 and beacon.size<0 at same time. It behaves like two **beaconManager.bind** , but I saw all the code. never that happends.

HomeFragment.kt

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(),RecyclerAdapterOutsideListener, BeaconConsumer {

    lateinit var beaconManager: BeaconManager
    val region = Region("myBeaons", null, null, null)
    var endOfScaning=false
    var isScanFirstTime=true

override fun getApplicationContext(): Context {
        return activity!!.applicationContext
    }

    override fun unbindService(p0: ServiceConnection?) {
        applicationContext.unbindService(p0!!)
    }

    override fun bindService(p0: Intent?, p1: ServiceConnection?, p2: Int): Boolean {
        return applicationContext.bindService(p0, p1!!, p2)
    }

override fun onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        beaconManager!!.removeAllMonitorNotifiers();
        beaconManager!!.addMonitorNotifier(object : MonitorNotifier {
            override fun didDetermineStateForRegion(p0: Int, p1: Region?) {
                Log.i(RangingActivity.TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: " + p0);
            }

            override fun didEnterRegion(p0: Region?) {
                Log.d(RangingActivity.TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time! + $p0.id1");

            }

            override fun didExitRegion(p0: Region?) {
                Log.d(RangingActivity.TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");
            }
        })


        beaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers()
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(object : RangeNotifier {
            override fun didRangeBeaconsInRegion(p0: MutableCollection<Beacon>?, p1: Region?) {
                if (p0!!.size > 0) {
                    Log.d("BeaconList", "didRangeBeaconsInRegion called with beacon count:  " + p0.size)
                    for (beacon in p0) {
                        Log.d("BeaconList", "uuid:  " + beacon.id1)

                        if (!finallist.uuids.contains(beacon.id1.toString())) {
                            finallist.uuids.add(beacon.id1.toString())
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d("deb","${p0.size} is > 0")
                    progress.visibility = View.GONE
                    homeRelative2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                    }
                if (p0.size<=0)
                {
                    Log.d("deb","${p0.size} is <= 0")
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Searching is done. There are not any supported places here.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    progress.visibility = View.GONE
                    homeRelative2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                endOfScaning=true
                if(endOfScaning)
                {
                    Log.d("deb","inside stop function")
                    endOfScaning=false
                    stopScan()

                }
            }

        })

    }
    
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(applicationContext)
        beaconManager.beaconParsers.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"))
        beaconManager.foregroundScanPeriod = 10000L
        beaconManager.foregroundBetweenScanPeriod=2000L
        beaconManager.updateScanPeriods()

        beaconManager.bind(this)

        startScan()

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        imgScan.setOnClickListener {
            finallist= uuidModel(ArrayList())
            Log.d("clearing finallist","${finallist.uuids}")
            recyclerAdapter.clearList()
            recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            startScan()
            progress.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            homeRelative2.visibility=View.GONE
        }
        }
        
         override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        beaconManager.unbind(this)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        beaconManager.unbind(this)
        super.onStop()
    }
    
        override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        if (beaconManager.isBound(this)) {
        beaconManager.unbind(this)

        }
    }
    
        fun startScan() {
        try {
            if (isScanFirstTime and beaconManager.isBound(this))
            {
                beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region)
                beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
                isScanFirstTime = false
            }
            else
            {
                beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
            }
        } catch (e: RemoteException) {
            Log.d("startScanFunction", "Start scan beacon problem", e)
        }
    }


    fun stopScan() {
        try {
            if (beaconManager.isBound(this)) {
                beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
            }

        } catch (e: RemoteException) {
            Log.d("startScanFunction", "Stop scan beacon problem", e)
        }
    }
}
```

I could handle this problem by **binding** before each scan and **unbinding** after each scan in startScan,StopScan functions.But I'm afraid that is standard or right stuff to do.

```
fun startScan() {
    try {
          if(!beaconManager.isBound(this))
          {
            beaconManager.bind(this)
          }
          if (isScanFirstTime and beaconManager.isBound(this))
          {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region)
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
            isScanFirstTime = false
          }
          else
          {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
          }
    }
    catch (e: RemoteException) {
        Log.d("startScanFunction", "Start scan beacon problem", e)
    }
}

fun stopScan() {
     try {
         if (beaconManager.isBound(this)) 
          {
            beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
            beaconManager.unbind(this)
          }
         }
     catch (e: RemoteException) 
       {
        Log.d("startScanFunction", "Stop scan beacon problem", e)
       }
}
```

Comment: The problem is likely caused by race conditions in the asynchronous bind/unbind calls combined with the timing of when startScanning/stopScanning  are called.  This is likely exacerbated by the complexities of the Fragment lifecycle.  While it is likely possible to get it working with this setup, it will require meticulous logging of each of these methods to track down cases where the sequence of calls is unexpected.  It will likely be faster to refactor the code to simplify these events.  Call bind just once if you can.  Perhaps leave ranging on while the user is on the screen.

Comment: Thank you David. I'm not sure that I can ask another question or not. That code above , I could run on android 9 easily. but when I run it in android 5.1 Lollipop . It said that you should use beaconManager.bind(). I used it in my onCreate method. weird behavior. After changing a lot I find out that I have to call startRangingBeaconsInRegion() in onBeaconServiceConnect() function to app work. I don't know why. in android version 9, I could call startRangingBeaconsInRegion in onCreate or button.setOnclickListener. What is it for?

Comment: I'm not sure where you are seeing something tell you to use "onBind" in Android 5.1. In general, the Fragment lifecycle is complex and short.  I would suggest you call bind() earlier -- when your activity or application starts up regardless of whether the fragment is being used yet.  Then don't call unbind until your activity or application are destroyed.  Binding over a longer term will produce much more predictable results.